# firebase rule if user email exists in subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to retrieve a document from clans collection where the docid is the clan name but i want to ensure that only the clan the user is in is retrievable.

clans collection contains documents with clanname as the id with a subcollection of members which contains documents with the user email as doc ids.

clans (collection) => clanname (document) => members (collection) => member(document)

How do I check the clan to make sure the request.auth.token.email is a document in the members subcollection

I think i need to get member to equal request.auth.token.email but not sure where to fit that in the rule.

```
      firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("clans")
    .doc(clanName)
    .get()
    .then(clan => {
      this.clan = clan;
    });


  match /clans/{clanName} {
        allow create;
      allow read: if exists(/databases/clans/documents/{clanName}/members/{member});
    }
```

the members subcollection would contain multiple documents with the user email as the documentIds.

Comment: Where do you expect `member` to come from?

Comment: request.auth.token.email, the documentid is email so they should match.

Comment: I would not use the email address as an ID.  The unique Firebase Auth UID is a much better choice for identifying users correctly.

Comment: why is that? i would need to rework some stuff for that recommendation. I store the users profile documents with email as the id as well.

is it for flexability on email?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the email address is unique between two user accounts, and email addresses change over time, but the UID will never. This is exactly the sort of thing that the UID is supposed to be used for.

Comment: good point on the multiple provider issue. Ill put that down as a task to swap over. the issue still remains even if its not email as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build the correct path to the document using the syntax described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) (which I do suggest reading thoroughly).  I suggest using the user's UID, as that is the best way to uniquely identify an account:

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/clans/{clanName}/members/$(request.auth.uid))
```

If you must use email, which I **strongly suggest avoid** for these sort of security rules, as you could run into problems later:

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/clans/{clanName}/members/$(request.auth.token.email))
```

Comment: what about adding the clan name into a custom claim since its really used for determining access to the clan or not?

Comment: Sure, you could try that as well.

Comment: Your comment on the uid got me rethinking the user profile i was storing and i wasnt storing anything other than the normal auth object data and clan name. so i could dump the entire profile collection.

Big help man thanks for your answer and uid suggestion!

Comment: I used the syntax in the above solution and still got an error for Missing or insufficient permissions. I can't seem to get any security to produce anything other than an error. Any reason as to why this would not work?

Comment: Without seeing the exact rules, data, and query, it's not possible to tell.  I suggest posting a new question with the specifics.